# Sass not load correct background SVG image using webpack

Tags: css, svg, webpack, sass

I have a following rules defined in the `webpack.config.js`

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['svgr/webpack', 'url-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'resolve-url-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-object-rest-spread'],
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see I use a [svgr](https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr) plugin to translate SVG images into a React components, and it works fine.

Troubles come when I want to use a SVG image as a background CSS property in `.scss` file.

`.scss` file with selector looks:

```
.some-name-class {
  background-image: url('../images/example.svg');
}
```

And following output is generated when I examine element by the Chrome Dev Tool:

[image: ChromeDevTool]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that svgr/webpack tries to return a React Object, when ever it encounters a .svg file. And the same is the output you found. which has an object in the output css file. To fix this, you can use the issuer differently. Eg:

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    issuer: /\.(js)x?$/,
    use: ['svgr/webpack']
},
{
   test: /\.svg$/,
    issuer: /\.css$/,
    use: ['svg-url-loader']
}
```